# stringify object array to JSON Selectively

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an Object array named users.
The object format in this array looks like this:

```
var userExample = {pub:{name:'John', id:'100'}, priv:{location:'NYC', phone:'000000'}};
```

As a restful service, clients may request information of all users.
And obviously I just want to send public information to them.
So I want to serialize my data selectively by keys(priv key will be ignored)

Here is my code snippet:

```
var users = [];
function censor(key, value) {
  if (key == priv) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return value;
}

app.get('/listUsers', function(req, res){
  res.end(JSON.stringify(users, censor));
});
```

When I run these code, an error occurred:

> ReferenceError: priv is not defined

I'm a Javascript beginner, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `priv` to `"priv"`.

But your approach is dangerous. In similar conditions I usually create a new object to export and I explicitly copy the properties which should be exported, this way there's no risk of leak on future data structure changes. A white list is always more future proof than a black list.

Comment: Thanks, you're correct. And thanks again for your advice, I'll try that way.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of JSON.stringify() have a [replacer array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter)

E.g.

````
```
JSON.stringify(foo, ['week', 'month']);  
// '{"week":45,"month":7}', only keep "week" and "month" properties
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
 if (key == "priv")
```

This should work.